# overview of differences between inheritance in python and java

Tags: java, python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a background in java, and I'm learning python. I'll need to be using inheritance soon, and I want to find out what any key differences are between how things are done in each of them. I've had a look online and found some information about differences between the two and what to look out for, and I've found that python supports multiple inheritance, but I'd like to know about any other differences specific to inheritance. I don't need to be told syntax (unless there is something I really need to watch out for), I've already taken a look at it and I'll be fine with that.

[Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)
[Python classes: Multiple Inheritance](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance)
[Python for Java programmers](http://python.computersci.org/Main/TableOfContents)

I can't really find exactly what I'm looking for which is an overview of differences and what to watch out for.

Comment: Please cite the information you already found.

Comment: As a data point: while multiple inheritance is *possible* in Python, it's not like it's used all over the place and something you need to be mindful of. Otherwise, Java's inheritance model is fairly straightforward - every method is virtual, and instance method calls get resolved using the runtime type of an object alone, and Python behaves the same when using equivalent constructs.

Comment: Is every method being virtual also the case in python?

Comment: @Harpy: well for quite a lot of programmers Java's multiple interface inheritance **IS** multiple inheritance and there are even OO languages that do not have the concept of "implementation inheritance" that do perfectly fine without it.  You're probably confusing "code reuse" and "inheritance".  I've got a 300 KLOC codebase here or so where we have used exactly **zero** times the *abstract* keyword and where there's not a single non-final class.  Besides that we're using multiple inheritance everywhere and yet this is Java so... As you can see "multiple inheritance" can mean different things.

Comment: Hm ok, I was just using multiple inheritance to mean in a way not supported in java, because that's the terminology I was taught. @SyntaxT3rr0r: I'll run over some stuff tomorrow to make sure I have those 2 clear, but no point when it's so late it's because early at the moment.

Comment: @NullUserException: Mm, I see how it can be seen as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has a fairly straightforward inheritance model: classes must have one (and only one) parent . You can't inherit from multiple parents, although you can implement multiple interfaces, which can be seen as Java's version of "multiple inheritance."

Most methods in Java classes are dynamically (late) bound, with the exception of methods declared `static`, `private` and `final` in the parent class.

In Python, as you have noted, you can inherit from multiple (or no) parents. Note that with multiple inheritance you can get the "[diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)." You should be aware of how Python resolves that and the implications this has when you refer to a parent class in Python (ie: who's your daddy?)

In Python, everything is dynamically bound, and since you can add members to an instance, not all instances of the same class are guaranteed to have the same members.

Finally, there's a slight difference in how constructors are overridden: In Java, children classes **must** call the parent's constructor (refinement overriding), whereas in Python children classes can override the constructor and not call the parent's constructor (replacement overriding).

Answer (score 2):

The most important concept to grasp when coming from a java background is that class inheritance is tool that is seldom required to solve problems in python.  The buzzword for this idea is *duck typing*.

Most of a python program is accessing and invoking the attributes on on object or another.  As in java, you can get useful behaviour by giving a function that expects an object of one type an object of another, more refined type.  For this to work in java, it's neccesary that the substituted object either inherit from the expected type, or implement the expected interface.

In python, that's not necessary at all; If the substituted object has all of the attributes the function you're passing it to expects, then it will just work.

The only reason to reach for inheritance in python is because the superclass really, genuinely does almost all of the things you need the new type to do, and you only have to add a few extra behaviours.

The most abundant example of this is the iterator protocol in python.  Any object that has a method `__iter__()` that returns the object itself and a `next()` method that returns anything at all is an iterator, and can appear a `for` statement.  `str`, `list`, `dict`, `file` and many other types, which have nothing much in common, and only the global `object` as common superclass, each implement the iterator protocol.

Comment: I'll be using it for making some custom widgets in pygtk, all the examples I've seen are subclasses of gtk.Widget, and I would be able to get most of the things I need through the superclass.